# Align text in label of a plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

[image]

Hi everyone. I am stuck at an issue where I need all my text to be aligned as I wish
I am using Woocommerce and a Plugin named MVV woocommerce booking where in the labels field I have put in my required text but even if I use the 
 tag the plugin doesn't read it. Also the plugin in the resource label doesn't accept more than 1 space else this could have been done. Attaching the front end and back end image for reference.
How to align the text in a nice way?

Comment: I tried adding this to Jquery but still doesn't work

$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(function() {
      return this.nodeValue.replace(/•/g,'<br/>');
  });